# "Default URL" value for site with iFrame

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have a site with iFrame. Site is hosted on "www.test.mycoolsite.com" and content for iFrame is loaded from "content.test.mycoolsite.com". GA integration will be for both parts - iFrame content and page which is hosting iFarme. Hits have be tracked in one GA property.

What should be used for "Default URL" when I create GA property?

Comment: It will make no difference for the tracking, however in-page analyses will only work for pages on the domain of the default url. Plus this is probably off-topic (no code involved) and should go to webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff  - Does it mean that - if I will set "Default URL" to "www.test.mycoolsite.com" then "in-page anbalytics" will not work for iFrame?

Comment: Yes, because the default url will be preprended to the page path (which will not give the desired result with the iframe url). However you can change the default url at any time whithout causing any harm.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff - sad thing is that if I change default url then changes are not taken into account. GA bug? Just by creating a new property I managed that my site is displayed in "in-page analytics" section. Tomorrow (when today's hits will be available) I will see whether it works.

Comment: As I've said this is most likely off-topic here (but you could still make clear if you are talking about "Website Url" or "Default Page" because there is no "Default Url"; I gathered that you meant Website Url).

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff - I am talking about "Default URL"! In GA for property settings there is such field as "Default URL".